# Do while loops have local variables in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a while statement like so:

```
    o = 0
    while o == 0:
        try:
            n = int(raw_input("Which number do you want to begin with?"))
            o = 1
        except:
            o = 0
            print "Please use a valid number."
```

However, when I try to use variable n later, it gives me the "local variable 'n' referenced before assignment' UnboundLocalError. That means that n cannot be recognized as a variable in the def I am using, because it only exists in the while statement? Is this possible?
The whole code:

```
import time
from sys import argv
import os
os.system("cls")

print "Welcome to Number counter 2.0!"
a = True
def program():
    global a
    if a == False:
        os.system("cls")
        o = 0
        while o == 0:
            try:
                n = int(raw_input("Which number do you want to begin with?"))
                o = 1
            except:
                o = 0
                print "Please use a valid number."
if n == "/historyKeep false":
    if a == False:
        print "Command historyKeep is already set to false."
    else:
        a = False
        print "Command set successfully."
elif n == "/historyKeep true":
    if a == True:
        print "Command historyKeep is already set to true."
    else:
        a = True
        print "Command set successfully."
if n == "/historyKeep false":
    n = raw_input("Which number do you want to begin with?")    
elif n == "/historyKeep true":
    n = raw_input("Which number do you want to begin with?")    

d = raw_input("How many seconds between each number?")
d = int(d)
total_s = n * d
while n > 0:
    print n
    time.sleep(d)
    n = n - 1
print "Done in", total_s, "seconds in total!"
end_q = raw_input("Exit or retry? (e/r)")
if end_q == "e":
    os.system("cls")
    print "Exiting."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print "Exiting.."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    print "Exiting..."
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("cls")
    exit(0)
elif end_q == "r":
    program()

program()
```

Comment: If `a == False` so that the first input loop runs, `n` will never equal any of those `"/historyKeep ..."` values, so none of those `if` statements will accomplish anything...

Comment: Why does this program insist on getting an integer for `n`, then repeatedly check whether it's a string (not to mention the fact that it duplicates those checks as well)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `a = True` at the beginning.  You then test if `a == False` and only set `n` if it is.  But then you test `n == "/history...`.   `n` has not been set at this point.

You need to make sure n is assigned before you use it.  It is not enough to just mention it in a branch that is not taken.

Answer (score 1):

n is not defined in the scope that you are trying to use it to fix this define it outside of the while loop and the if statement the while loop is in:

```
global a
n = 0
```

Then when you ask the user for what number to start with, that value will replace 0, and you should be good to go. Also instead of declaring `global a`, why not just make a an input argument for the `program()` function?

Comment: That isn't a fix because it's outside the `while` loop, it's a fix because it's outside the `if` branch.

Comment: How exactly do I make an input argument?

Comment: `def program(a):` and to call it you do `program(a)`. Wherever you call the function `program()` you have to replace it with `program(a)`

Comment: Oh, okay. I tried to do that but forgot to replace all program() to program(a), I just did one of them, so it didn't work. Thanks, did that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, declare `n` outside of the loop first:

```
n = None
while True:
    try:
        n = int(raw_input("Text..."))
        break
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid number!")
```

Note: Usually, you would use `break` to exit a loop. This is because your method requires an extra variable, which uses more memory (not much, but if you keep doing it, it will stack up).

Comment: Okay, used break instead. Thanks!